# How to check if my laptop screen is broken or it's the internal cable?

Tags: laptop, display, laptop-repair, acer

I have an acer nitro 5 laptop and the built in screen is not working properly. The majority of the screen is black, only the top part is showing images.

If I use it on my Ubuntu instead of Windows and set it to 60Hz, it works almost perfecty, with minor flaws that are hard to notice.

I want to know if it is the internal cable that is problematic or it is the screen itself. How can i check it?

Comment: About the only thing you can do to help isolate is to try to re-seat both ends of the cable and see.

Comment: The cheapest option is to use a different cable, the more expensive option is to use a different display, the free option is to verify the cable is securely connected. However, if you have not disconnected the cable, before this issue surfaced, then the problem likely is the display.

Comment: Since Ubuntu works, it cannot be the physical display. It could be cable, timing issues, or a host of other causes.